# Need Help debugging a null point exception in Android application (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Heres my MainActivity java code:

```
package peter_seeproductions.deapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
class Body{
    String eng;
    String ger;
    public Body(String a, String b){
        eng = a;
        ger = b;
    }
    public Body(){

    }
}
class buttonVal{

    Body word = new Body();
    public buttonVal(Body x){
        word = x;
    }

    public buttonVal() {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
buttonVal btn1 = new buttonVal();
buttonVal btn2 = new buttonVal();
buttonVal btn3 = new buttonVal();
buttonVal btn4 = new buttonVal();

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

public void List(int btn){
    ArrayList<Body> list = new ArrayList<Body>();

    list.add(new Body("der Finger","Finger"));
    list.add(new Body("der Oberarm","Upper arm"));
    list.add(new Body("der Unterarm","Lower arm"));
    list.add(new Body("der Ellbogen","Elbow"));
    list.add(new Body("die Hüfte","Hip"));
    list.add(new Body("der Oberschenkel","Upper leg"));
    list.add(new Body("der Unterschenkel","Lower leg"));
    list.add(new Body("das Knie","Knee"));
    list.add(new Body("die Zehe","Toe"));
    list.add(new Body("der Fuss","Foot"));
    list.add(new Body("das Bein","Leg"));
    list.add(new Body("die Hand","Hand"));
    list.add(new Body("der Bauch","Abdomen"));
    list.add(new Body("der Nabel","Bellybutton"));
    list.add(new Body("der Arm","Arm"));
    list.add(new Body("die Brust","Breast"));
    list.add(new Body("die Schulter","Shoulder"));
    list.add(new Body("der Hals","Throat"));
    list.add(new Body("der Mund","Mouth"));
    list.add(new Body("die Nase","Nose"));
    list.add(new Body("das Auge","Eye"));
    list.add(new Body("das Haar","Hair"));
    list.add(new Body("der Kopf","Head"));

    int q1,q2,q3,q4;

    if (btn == 0){

        q1 = (int)(Math.random()* (list.size() - 1));
        do {
            q2 = (int)(Math.random()*(list.size() - 1));
        }while(q2 == q1);
        do {
            q3 = (int)(Math.random()*(list.size() - 1));
        }while(q3 == q2 || q3 == q1);
        do {
            q4 = (int)(Math.random()*(list.size() - 1));
        }while(q4 == q3||q4==q2||q4==q1);

        btn1.word = list.get(q1);
        btn2.word = list.get(q2);
        btn3.word = list.get(q3);
        btn4.word = list.get(q4);

        button1.setText(btn1.word.ger);
        button2.setText(btn2.word.ger);
        button3.setText(btn3.word.ger);
        button4.setText(btn4.word.ger);
    }

}
public void Next(View view){
    List(0);
}
```

}

It all seems to be fine, however when I run it I get a null pointer exception which crashes the app. I have not been doing java for too long, and I am not very good at finding these bugs. When I run I get this error code:

```
03-07 23:55:43.885 32387-32387/peter_seeproductions.deapp E/AndroidRuntime:    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: peter_seeproductions.deapp, PID: 32387
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{peter_seeproductions.deapp/peter_seeproductions.deapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1892)
at peter_seeproductions.deapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:79)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Ive tried looking for the null pointer but I really have no clue

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
```

to `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

First..you need to move `findViewById()`s to inside `onCreate()` after the call to `setContentView()`. That is how activity knows what layout to map with which components. 
 About reading the logs,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1892)  
at peter_seeproductions.deapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:79)
```

the lines above tell you that the NPE is occuring on line number 79 of your `MainActivity.java`.

Second.. make sure you have the id(s) defined in the layout for all components properly like button1, button2 and ensure that those id are being matched with your project's R.java and not the android's R..  I suggest you read a bit more about android development and esp about ui, layouts and related xml(s).

Here..[Accessing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) would be a good place to start with.

Comment: Thanks, it seems moving the button statements to into a method fixed the problem. I feel silly now seeing as how simple it was.

Comment: Thats alright..it happens to everybody, at one point or another. I suggested avoid id(s) like button1 and read through because [android.R.id.button1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#button1) and ambiguity of R.java also leads to waste of time, unnecessary type..

Answer (score 0):

replace your `onCreate()` method with this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

}
```